# Am I doing this jQuery Click() function correctly?

Tags: jquery, css, click

I am trying to make it so that when users click on my `<div class="fb-like"></div>`, everything on the page will have it's css be changed to `overflow: visible`

Here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fb-like").click(function() {
   $("*").css("overflow", "visible");
});
});
```

Is this correct? Because it's not working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nothing wrong : http://jsfiddle.net/z3PKg/ . Are you linking jQuery?

Comment: Maybe you're adding `.fb-like` after the page has loaded. If so, use: `$(document).on('click', '.fb-like', function() {...}):`

Comment: try using `.on('click', function()...` instead. if thats being added to the DOM after the page loads it may not be seeing it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use on();

http://api.jquery.com/on/

And use a class on the HTML element. Changing the style attribute on every single item on the page is not a good idea, performance-wise.

```
$('.fb-like').on('click', function(){
     $('html').addClass('overflow-visible');
});
```

And CSS:

```
.overflow-visible * {overflow: visible}
```

Comment: `.on('click',` is functionally equivalent to `.click(` as the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/) themselves state.